# Curling Jersey endpoints yields "Couldn't find a span for the current request"

Tags: java, curl, jersey, dropwizard

I'm encountering a truly inexplicable bug when using a Dropwizard server with custom JAX-RS resources registered with a Jersey server. The following are true:

1. Curling a nonexistent endpoint yields a 404, as expected.
2. Curling an existing endpoint with the wrong method (e.g. POST instead of GET) yields a 405, as expected.
3. Curling an existing endpoint with the right method yields the message "Couldn't find a span for the current request".
4. My endpoint handler code is never touched, as can be verified by setting breakpoints in the code.
5. Amazingly, if I move the entire path annotation onto my handler method instead of partly on the entire class, I get a 404 instead.

Here's an example of the format that gives the strange error message:

```
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Path("application/api/v1/")
public class GetConfigurationResource extends MyResource<Arg, Result> {

  @GET
  @Path("getConfiguration/{uuid}")
  public Response handleHttpRequest(
      @Context HttpHeaders headers, @Context UriInfo uriInfo, @PathParam("uuid") String uuid) {
    return super.handleHttpRequest(headers, new Arg(), new Result());
  }
}
```

Here's an example that gives a 404:

```
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public class GetConfigurationResource extends MyResource<Arg, Result> {

  @GET
  @Path("application/api/v1/getConfiguration/{uuid}")
  public Response handleHttpRequest(
      @Context HttpHeaders headers, @Context UriInfo uriInfo, @PathParam("uuid") String uuid) {
    return super.handleHttpRequest(headers, new Arg(), new Result());
  }
}
```

Here's the curl command:

```
curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/application/api/v1/getConfiguration/5
```

I can reproduce this error even when using toy classes like this in my application. Every single endpoint gives the same result.

A simple Google search of the error message yields absolutely no results. So this seems like a completely novel error. I'm wondering what could possibly cause something like this, and how I could debug this inside Dropwizard/Jersey.

Comment: Wild guess: are there any JAX-RS annotations on `MyResource`?

Comment: Nope. Even providing trivial resources that don't implement any superclass gives the same result.